# Save string to plist remove old data

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I successfully added my dictionary to plist but when i add 2nd time it remove my old dictionary from my plist. 
Here is my code :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favQuote.plist"];


NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:self.txtQuote.text,@"quote",self.lblAuthor.text,@"author",nil];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListWriteStreamError error:&error];

if(plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Data saved sucessfully");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data not saved");
}
```

How do I add my new dictionary without losing old data?

Comment: 2nd time it's writing dictionary with the same name!

Comment: yes i have to add my dic to plist, that have same key

Comment: If you use same key name then it's override new data to old one.

Comment: In what format you want final data ?

Comment: Final data is in array @Lion

Comment: i have to store dic to plist which user add to favourite, so plist contain all favourite dictionary. @kb920

Answer (score 0):

You should store your dictionary of array in your document directory something like,

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favQuote.plist"];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if ( [manager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    arr = (NSMutableArray*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];


}


NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"test",@"quote",@"test2",@"author",nil];

[arr addObject:plistDict];


NSData *plistData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr];



if(plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Data saved sucessfully");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data not saved");
}
```

then you can retrieve and use your values like,

```
   NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if ( [manager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    arr1 = (NSMutableArray*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];


}
if (arr1.count > 0) {

    NSDictionary *firstDic = [arr1 objectAtIndex:0];

}
```